# Setting additional jars property in Pig while running in local mode

Tags: apache-pig

When Pig is running in distributed (HDFS) mode, you can pass additional jars to it from command-line using the following syntax, so that you don't have to explicitly using the `REGISTER` call

```
pig -Dpig.additional.jars=jar1.jar:jar2.jar -f pigfile.pig
```

But when I do the same thing while running in local mode, it fails

```
pig -x local -Dpig.additional.jars=jar1.jar:jar2.jar -f pigfile.pig
```

Does anyone know how to register additional jars while running Pig in local mode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Properties should be passed before any Pig-specific options:

```
pig -Dpig.additional.jars=jar1.jar:jar2.jar -x local -f pigfile.pig
```

Comment: When I do this in local mode, Pig is failing and shows me the list of default usage patterns. (Basically fails to parse the command line parameters)

Comment: That's strange since I am using the same version of Pig as well `Apache Pig version 0.10.0 (r1328203) 
compiled Apr 19 2012, 22:54:12` I am passing some parameters using `-p` option. Does that matter?

Comment: It is working now. I moved the `-p` values after `-Dpig.additional.jars` options. Thanks